# How to pass array in POST API?

Tags: laravel, loops, post, foreach

I'm trying to post booking content with array of passengers but it always return invalid argument supplied for foreach(). What seems to be the problem ?

```
public function postBooking(Request $request)
        {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate(); 

            $booking = Booking::create([
                'service_name' => $request->get('service_name'),
                'service_package' => $request->get('service_package'),
                'travel_date' => $request->get('travel_date'),
                'travel_day' => $request->get('travel_day'),
                'travel_time' => $request->get('travel_time'),
                'remark' => $request->get('remark'),
                'booking_name' => $request->get('booking_name'),
                'mobile_number' => $request->get('mobile_number'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'nationality' => $request->get('nationality'),
                'user_id' => $user->user_id,
            ]);

            $passengers = $request['passengers'];

            if(is_array($passengers))
            {
                    foreach($passengers as $passenger) 
                {
                    $passenger = Passenger::create([
                        'passenger_name' => $passenger['passenger_name'],
                        'ic_passport' => $passenger['ic_passport'],
                        'booking_id' => $booking->booking_id
                    ]);
                }   
            }

            $response = (object)[];
            $response->booking = $booking->makeHidden('users');
            $response->passengers = $passengers;

    return response()->json(['data'=>$response, 'status'=>'ok']);
        }
```

Comment: First of all, you must inspect `$request->passengers` with `dd()`.

Comment: How are you passing the array to the route? lets see the form

Answer (score 0):

var_dump the  $passengers, in my opinion ,the way u get the data from $request is wrong, u show use var_dump()or dd() to see the structure of $request and mostly u can solve the problem.